# Is there a length restriction on a SQL Case Statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I am writing a very basic SQL `CASE` statement in a stored procedure with 1,700 lines of variables: i.e.

```
CASE Color  
    WHEN '1' THEN 'Blue'
    WHEN '2' THEN 'Red'
    .....
    WHEN '1700' THEN 'Violet'
    ELSE Color
END as 'color'
```

Is there a maximum length that I am exceeding? The stored procedure builds but when I call it from a website I get a runtime error (when I only have 1300 it works fine).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i voted to move this question to dba. besides that if you have 1700 lines of a case statement like the above you are missing a lookup table that would avoid the issue completely with a simple join...

Comment: The better choice would be to add those codes of color into a `Colors` table and doing a `JOIN` instead of that gigantic `CASE` expression. @Paolo I don't think that this is a good fit for DBA

Comment: yes you should create a table and join with table. which will give you normalized data, suppose you make this SP or Function it would be very problematic to handle in future

Comment: @Lamak the question is not about optimization of this query (issue that may be it on so) but about limits on stored procedures length.

Comment: @Paolo we already know that it isn't an issue about length in op's case, since the stored procedure works. The problem is when it's called from a website, which is not on topic for DBA

Comment: Does it run properly when you run the proc locally?

Comment: @Lamak you're right, i overlooked that point

Comment: Are you saying that the procedure works from SSMS but not from your website because it's too long? That can't be the case... Also, what is the error?

Comment: "I get a runtime error" And that error is?

Comment: Seconding what @JamesZ says. If it was indeed a stored procedure, you wouldn't have issues about its length regardless of where you call it from. Your website was likely sending a long *ad-hoc query* to the server rather than calling a *stored* (i.e. stored in the database server) procedure. An ad-hoc query is not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The only limit on `CASE` expressions I'm aware of is that you can't nest them more than 10 deep, which is irrelevant to what you're doing.   Stored procs have a length limit of 250MB or batch size, whichever is smaller, but pretty sure that would prevent you from building the proc in the first place, and unlikely you've hit that limit.

Maybe someone else can identify a technical reason for this to fail, but one thing is clear, you should be using a lookup table that contains all pairs of numbers and colors, so you can `JOIN`, something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.Color_Name,a.Color)
FROM YourTable a
LEFT JOIN lkp_Colors b
  ON a.Color = b.Color_ID
```